# Scala Map syntax

Tags: scala, dictionary

While reviewing the code for the water pouring problem in the Coursera Scala class, I came across two uses of map where I don't understand the syntax.

I'm used to:

```
a.map(b => b * b)
```

But I'm seeing:

```
a map something
```

For example:

```
next <- moves map path.extend
```

does this mean "for each next in moves, path.extend(next)"?

```
paths #:: from(more, explored ++ (more map (_.endstate)))
```

does this mean "add the endstate of more to explored"?

Comment: Scala syntax allows the standard method invocation `obj.meth(arg)` to be expressed with spaces `obj meth arg`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In scala, the following expressions are equivalent:

```
moves map path.extend
moves map(path.extend)
moves.map(path.extend)
moves.map(m => path.extend(m))
```

And the following are equivalent:

```
more map (_.endstate)
more.map(_.endstate)
more.map(m => m.endstate)
```

Comment: `moves.map(path.extend)` and `moves.map(m => path.extend(m))` are not equivalent: `def a(x: Int)(y: Int) = x + y; List(1).map(a); List(1).map(x => a(x))` (last statement won't compile)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, I think you're correct about `next <- moves map path.extend`

I'm assuming you're talking about a "for comprehension". For example,

```
val a = List (1, 3, 5)

a.map(b => b * b)
  //> res0: List[Int] = List(1, 9, 25)

for {
  blah <- a map (b => b * b)
} yield blah  
  //> res1: List[Int] = List(1, 9, 25)
```

You can see these two return the same result and are equivalent in Scala.

So we're saying for every element in "a" call the function (b => b * b).

---

In your example it's more like this scenario:

```
case class Song(artists:List[String], title: String)

val songs = List(Song(List("Michael Jackson", "Janet Jackson"), "Scream"),
                             Song(List("Janet"), "Unbreakable"))

for {
  song <- songs
  artist <- song.artists
  if artist startsWith "Mic"
} yield song.title                                
  //> res0: List[String] =     List(Scream)

songs.flatMap(
    song => song.artists.withFilter(artist => artist startsWith "Mic").map(artist => song.title)
)                                                 
  //> res1: List[String] = List(Scream)
```

You can see these are also equivalent but the "for-comprehension" is easier to read.

Comment: Yes!  I took that line from this code:
     `def from(paths: Set[Path], explored: Set[State]): Stream[Set[Path]] =
      if (paths.isEmpty) Stream.empty
      else {
         val more = for {
        path <- paths
        next <- moves map path.extend
        if !(explored contains next.endState)
      } yield next
      paths #:: from(more, explored ++ (more map (_.endState)))
    }`

Comment: In that case I think it's more of a combination of a flatMap and withFilter. I'm adding some new info to the answer above. Hope it helps.